# Displaying a localized time using JodaTime

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I want to display a time "18:36" in locales that use a 24-hour clock but display it as "6:36 pm" in locales that use a 12-hour clock, and also have it formatted appropriately for other locales that I'm not familiar with. Is there a simple way to accomplish this with JodaTime?

Incidentally, I'm doing this on Android, but I imagine it's the same as any Java platform.

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html

Comment: Android is not quite the same. For example, mobile phone users can choose themselves 24h versus 12h format, see also this [discussion](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/issues/16): So the whole subject is not only about preferred localized settings. The best thing in Joda-Time is just choosing a [format style)(http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle-java.lang.String-) ignoring Android user preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
String str = date.toString(fmt);
```

source: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html